# How can we better understand multiplicative inverse modulo something?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, inverse

How can we intuitively understand modulo multiplicative inverse?

Suppose we have an ring $\mathbb{Z}_{13}= \{0, 1, 2, 3, \ldots, 12\}$.

Each element except zero has corresponding multiplicative inverse.

Below is the mapping of inverse.

1 $\rightarrow$ 1

2 $\rightarrow$ 7

3 $\rightarrow$ 9

4 $\rightarrow$ 10

5 $\rightarrow$ 8

6 $\rightarrow$ 11

7 $\rightarrow$ 2

8 $\rightarrow$ 5

9 $\rightarrow$ 3

10 $\rightarrow$ 4

11 $\rightarrow$ 6

12 $\rightarrow$ 12

Now, I want to consider division by 2, which here means that multiplication by 7.
However, some integer multiplied 7 becomes acutally the same result as division by 2 over real number field.
For example, the following holds.

4 * 7 = 28 = 2 mod 13;
6 * 7 = 42 = 3 mod 13;
etc.

On the other hand, other values do not produce the same result over real number fields.

For example,
5 * 7 = 35 = 9 mod 13 (I want this value to be 2 or 3 since 5/2 = 2.5)

7 * 7 = 49 = 10 mod 13 (I want this value to be 3 or 4 since 7/2 = 3.5).

Why some values produce the same result as over the real number field, and the others do not??

Comment: I think you mean $35=9$, which you'll notice is $22=11\times 2$. similarly, $7=20=2\times 10$.

Comment: Yeah, that's true. Thank you for your suggestion! I have corrected it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Operations mod $n$ aren't guaranteed to preserve the order inherited from the reals.

So the fact that in $\mathbb{R}$, we have
$$2 < {\small{\frac{5}{2}}} < 3$$
doesn't imply
$$2 < ({\small{\frac{5}{2}}}\;\text{mod}\;13) < 3$$
However what *is* true is that, working mod $13$, we have
$$
{\small{\frac{5}{2}}} = 2+{\small{\frac{1}{2}}} = 2+7 = 9
\qquad\;\;\;
$$
and also
$${\small{\frac{5}{2}}} = 3-{\small{\frac{1}{2}}} = 3-7 = -4 = 9$$

Comment: Hi, I found that $\frac{5}{2} \mod 13 = \frac{5 - 13}{2} = -4 \equiv 9 \mod 13$. How can I generalize this??

Answer (score 1):

When your modulus is a prime number like $13$ you actually have a field and you may define fractions within your field.

For example $7=1/2$ and $10=1/4$
If you multiply $7\times 7=49=10$ you notice that it is the same as $$1/2 \times 1/2 =1/4$$

The problem which puzzles you is confusing the field of equivalency classes with the field of real numbers.

In the field of equivalency classes you have $$5/2 =5\times 7=9$$

Now if you multiply $9\times 2$ you get $18$  which is $5$ as it should be.

Note that $2.5$ makes sense in real field but you do not have a class of $2.5$ mod $13$ instead you have class of $9$ which serves well as $5/2$

Comment: Thank you for your clear explanation!

Comment: Thank you for your attention and understanding

Answer (score 0):

Because that doesn't work even for the number $2$. Note that $11\times7=77\equiv12\pmod{13}$. However, $\frac{11}2=5.5$, which is *not* near $12$.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. So, is there any bridge between 5.5 and 12 in this case?

Comment: None whatsoever.

Comment: Note:  $\dfrac{11+13}2=12$

Comment: $11\equiv -2\bmod 13\implies {11\over 2}\equiv -1\equiv 12\bmod 13$

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I see.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee This is interesting (at least for me). So, you are saying that considering values in $\{-6, -5, ...,0 ,1, 2, ..., 6 \}$ makes things easier?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I'm wondering why you add 13...?

Comment: it can, but I was more just turning odds into their even equivalents mod an odd number.

Comment: $13$ is the modulus; $12\times2\equiv11\mod13$ means $ 12\times2=13k+11 (k=1)$

Comment: @mallea There *is* a "bridge", viz.  $\ 5.5 = 5 + \dfrac{\color{#c00}{\bf 1}}2 \equiv 5 + \dfrac{\color{#c00}{14}}2 \equiv  12\pmod{\color{#c00}{\!\!13}}\ \ $

Answer (score 0):

Note that $5 \times 7 = 35 = 9 \pmod{13}$, not 11 as you claimed in your question -- and, given this, it might help to observe that we can also think of $2.5$ as $2.5 = 2 + .5 = 2 + 2^{-1} = 2 + 7 = 9 \pmod{13}$.

Answer (score 0):

If $b$ is invertible mod $c$, 
$ab^{-1} \equiv c \mod p$ is equivalent to $a \equiv b c \mod p$, and this means $a = b c + k p$ for some integer $k$.  Sometimes you'll have $k = 0$, so $a = b c$ and $c = a/b$ (as integers), sometimes you won't.

Answer (score -1):

What you seek is generally impossible. Suppose that $\,b\,$ is invertible $\!\bmod n,\,$ i.e. $\,\gcd(b,n)=1\,$ and let's calculate the fraction $\,a/b = ab^{-1}\pmod{\! n},\,$ where $\, 0 < a,b < n$.

By division $\,a = q\,b+r\ $ thus $\bmod n\!:\,\ a/b\equiv ab^{-1} \equiv (qb+r)b^{-1}\equiv q + \color{#c00}{rb^{-1}}$

When $\,r = 0\,$ we get $\!\bmod n\!:\ (qb)/b\equiv q,\,$ same as in $\Bbb R,\,$ when $\,a/b\in\Bbb Z\,$ is an *exact* quotient.

Else $\,\color{#0a0}{0<r<b}\,$ and you want $\,\color{#c00}{rb^{-1}}\equiv 0\,\ {\rm  or}\,\ 1\, \Longrightarrow\, \color{#0a0}{r\equiv  0\,\ {\rm or}\,\ b},\,$  contradiction.

**Note** $ $ It can be true for fractions with $\,a,b > n\,$ if they reduce to exact quotients $(r= 0),\,$ e.g.

$$\bmod 13\!:\ \ \dfrac{13}{27}\equiv \dfrac{0}1 = \left\lfloor \dfrac{13}{27}\right\rfloor,\ \ \dfrac{14}{27}\equiv \dfrac{1}1 = \left\lceil \dfrac{14}{27} \right\rceil\qquad\qquad\qquad $$

Comment: It's not from me. thank you for your answer! Btw, is it possible to generalize your approach using ceiling and flooring?

Comment: @mallea I wasn't sure how you sought to "round",  so I gave examples both ways. But the point was to emphasize that it won't work work in many cases.